# Teams help center - $SiteName

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Badges-Overview page seems to have some bad content in bold below:

https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042872-badges-overview

Silver badges. Silver badges are for experienced users who regularly use **$SiteName**. They encourage continued participation and returning to the site by awarding longer term goals. Silver badges are more uncommon than bronze badges, but attainable if you're dedicated.

Comment: Can you please place an answer so I can accept and close this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.